# What is the difference between "GLOBAL" and "STATIC" variable in PHP?

Tags: php

What exactly is the difference between the GLOBAL and STATIC variables in PHP? And which one is preferable to use, when we want to use a variable in multiple functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A static variable just implies that the var belongs to a class but can be referenced without having to instantiate said class. A global var lives in the global namespace and can be referenced by any function in any class. Global vars are always frowned upon because they're so easily misused, overwritten, accidentally referenced, etc. At least with static vars you need to reference via `Class::var;`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation against class:var, but for this context i am concerned about the variable declared STATIC in a function

Answer (score 2):

Global is used to get the global vars which may be defined in other scripts, or not in the same scope.

e.g.

```
<?php

$g_var = 1;

function test() {
   var_dump($GLOBAL['g_var']);

   global $g_var;
   var_dump($g_var);
}
```

Static is used to define an var which has whole script life, and init only once.

e.g.

```
<?php

function test() {
    static $cnt = 0;
    $cnt ++;
    echo $cnt;
} 

$i = 10;

while (-- $i) {
    test();
}
```

Comment: so you mean, global can be changed any time but static is kind of constant ??

Comment: @Unknown no, i do not mean that. static vaiable could be changed freely. But the init operation run only once. See my example, "static $cnt = 0" only run once, then every time the func called, the variable is added by one.

Answer (score 1):

A global variable is a variable which is defined in a scope and can span to included and required scopes. (*in simple terms by scope I mean the php file/function/class*)

Here are some examples of how global variables work.

**Example 1:** Variable declared in scope and used in function using `global` keyword

```php
<?php
$a = 1;

function add_a() {
    global $a;
    $a++;
}

add_a();

echo $a;
```

In the above example we declare variable `$a` and assign it value `1` in the scope. We then declare a function `add_a` in the same scope and try to increment the `$a` variable value. The `add_a` function is called and then we `echo` the `$a` variable expecting the result to display `2`.

**Example 2:** Variable declared in scope and used in function using the `$GLOBALS` variable

```php
<?php
$a = 1;

function add_a() {
    $GLOBALS['a']++;
}

add_a();

echo $a;
```

The result from example 2 above is exactly the same as the result from example 1.

> There is no difference with using the `global` keyword and the special PHP defined `$GLOBALS` array variable. However they both have their advantages and disadvantages.
>
> Read more about `$GLOBALS` on official PHP website [$GLOBALS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

If you want to span a scope declared variable to a included or required scope see example below.

**Example 3:**
file `a.php`

```php
<?php
global $a;
$a = 1;

require 'b.php';

add_a();

echo $a;
```

file `b.php`

```php
<?php
function add_a() {
    global $a;
    $a++;
}
```

In the above example we have file `a.php` and `b.php`. File `b.php` is required in file `a.php` because we use a function declared in file `b.php`. To use the `$a` variable in file `b.php` we must first declare `$a` as global to be used outside the local scope and we do this by first calling `global $a` and then we define a value like so `$a = 1`. Variable $a is now available to be used anywhere in any included scopes by first calling `global $a` before manipulation.

**Static Variables**
Usually found in classes but in some well developed PHP project you can find them in recursive functions. A static variable is a variable that remembers its value and can be reused every time the function or method is called.

Here are some examples of a static variable in use.

**Example 1:** Static variable in a function

```php
function add() {
    static $a = 1;
    $a++;

    echo $a;
}

add(); //2
add(); //3
add(); //4
```

**Example 2:** Static variable in class

```
class A {
    public static $a = 1;

    public static function add() {
        self::$a++;
        echo self::$a;
    }
}

echo A::$a; //1
A::add(); //2

echo A::$a; //2
A::add(); //3

echo A::$a; //3
A::add(); //4
```

> Note that you cannot assign a return value from a function to a static variable. For example you cannot do `static $a = rand()`. See Example 3 below on how to assign return value to static variable.

**Example 3:** Assign return variable from function to static variable

```php
function add() {
    static $a;
    $a = rand();

    echo $a;
}
```

> Read more about global and static variables on PHP official website [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

Global variable is created before the function is created, but global keyword is added in function

```
$g_var = 1;

function test() {
  var_dump($GLOBAL['g_var']);
  global $g_var;
  var_dump($g_var);
}
```

static is created and declared static in function

```
function test() {
  static $cnt = 0;
  $cnt ++;
  echo $cnt;
}

$i = 10;

while(--$i) test();
```