# What's the difference between static variables and globals in php?

Tags: php, variables, static, global

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between “GLOBAL” and “STATIC” variable in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266038/what-is-the-difference-between-global-and-static-variable-in-php)

if we create a static variable inside a function, this variable exists in further using of the function... and as far as I know global variable does the same.
now what's the benefit of using static variables?

Comment: They don't pollute the global scope? You can have two functions using `static $cache` without stepping on each other...

Comment: If I Google your question right now do you think I will find answers? I think I will. And I bet like 2 bucks that some of those answers will even be on this site.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov well i didn't find my answer. and if you show me an article about it i'll be grateful.

Comment: @naveen see this link it may be useful for you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266038/what-is-the-difference-between-global-and-static-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lexical scope of a `static` static variable is restricted to the function body – you cannot access the variable outside the function.
However, its value will be remembered across multiple calls of the same function.

Global variables exist in global scope and can be accessed from anywhere in your code (you have to use the `global` keyword or `$GLOBALS` array inside functions though)

Answer (score 3):

A static variable just implies that the var belongs to a class but can be referenced without having to instantiate said class. A global var lives in the global namespace and can be referenced by any function in any class. Global vars are always frowned upon because they're so easily misused, overwritten, accidentally referenced, etc. At least with static vars you need to reference via Class::var;

Comment: The question is about static variables inside functions, not about class variables.

Comment: A static variable is initialized only once